# Xamarin.UiTest querying controls without id and text

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

How to query Xamarin.Froms controls, which examined by repl() don't have id and text. One example is a SwitchCell with Text and On properties set in XAML. I would rather prefer a solution (if it's possible) that doesn't require editing XAML views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.Tap(c => c.Marked("NameOfControl"));
```

It also depends what controls etc. Paste what u have on Repl() or screenshot it so we can help. You didn't provide enough information.